# Conditionally show/hide Region Display Selector items

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have two regions on the page with the same title, so I cannot use APEX hide region dynamic action and forced to use javascript.
Both regions are part of Region display selector.
I gave each region different static ID - ``` Region`` and ```Region2`.

I am hiding a second region and displaying the first one using javascript dynamic action:

```
$("#Region2").hide();
$("#Region1").show();
```

The thing is, both regions are still accessible via Region Display Selector. How can I hide one of the regions from the display selector?

Answer (score 1):

I would try these options in that order:

1 - Put these regions inside a "container" region, this container region is "blank with attributes". You need to control this container region in the selector and not the two childs.

2 - This control, show or not show, can not be done as a server-side condition?

3 - Define a static id of these regions and use hide() or show() to do this. 
And you can access your respective tab like this.
Example:

```
//alfa4 is the static ID of my region report
$("li[aria-controls='SR_alfa4']").hide()
$("li[aria-controls='SR_alfa4']").show()
```

You can test in this page: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:12